# ORACLE SQL Second Maximum Salary

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

How to find Second Maximum salary drawn by the employee from Employees table. Whether is it possible to find it through ROWNUM function.

example table:

```
S.no    Name       employee_id     salary
201     Steven        100            1000
202     Alexander     101            2500 
203     Daniel        102            5000
204     John          103            3000
205     Ishanth       104            8000
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Can you provide sample rows from which you are trying to find second maximum salary?

Comment: provide atleast the table

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned second highest salary, you should be using `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` if there are two employees with the same-highest value which will give you the highest salary by mistake even when you give `WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 2` condition.

```
SELECT A.S_NO, A.NAME, A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.SALARY
FROM
    (SELECT S_NO, NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY, 
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS SALARY_RANK) A
WHERE A.SALARY_RANK = 2;
```

Comment: Don't know why somebody downvoted this, it's a perfectly good answer.

Comment: This is frustrating!

Comment: The only fix I would mention would be to add the missing `FROM` like `AS SALARY_RANK FROM A)`. That provided me the correct answer with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can use Nth_Value function here
Please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF30031 for syntax

```
select distinct 
nth_value(salary,2) OVER (ORDER BY salary desc range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as secondVal 
from HR.EMPLOYEES;
```

Another option, is using DENSE_RANK function as follows

```
with cte as (
    select salary, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as nth_salary from Employee
)
select salary from cte 
where 
    nth_salary = 2;
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: What happens if there are two employees with the highest salary?

Comment: Let's say if there are two max values, assume top 2 salaries are same with 100, then this query will return 100. Not the following one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT salary FROM (SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM Employees  ORDER BY salary 
DESC) WHERE ROWNUM=2;
```

Where,

- `salary` is the column Name
- `Employees` is the table name

or

Simplest way to fetch second max salary & nth salary

```
select 
 DISTINCT(salary) 
from Employees 
 order by salary desc 
limit 1,1
```

Note:

```
limit 0,1  - Top max salary

limit 1,1  - Second max salary

limit 2,1  - Third max salary

limit 3,1  - Fourth max salary
```

### Update for oracle

```
SELECT salary FROM (
    SELECT salary, row_number() OVER (order by salary desc) AS rn FROM Employees
)
WHERE rn = 2
```

Comment: upvoted but oracle doesn't support the `limit`

Comment: You are adding sql tag for this question.that's why I gave this answer in sql . Please find a way to limit in oracle

Comment: @APC I have update my answer.

Comment: @Rams I have update my answer

Comment: `ROWNUM=2` doesn't work the way you think it does; that query will return **zero** rows.

Comment: @APC, Greate Catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use general query for max nth salary:

```
select salary from table_name order by salary desc limit n-1,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using ROWNUM .You can easily find the 'n' th salary by

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT  salary 
  FROM Employees
  ORDER BY salary DESC limit 2
  ) a
ORDER BY a.salary limit 1
```

Here instead of "2" you can give any "n" value you required.